# Self implementation of pipe, how to know how many processes has file descriptors to my pipe?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, file-descriptor

I need to self implement a pipe, that will have regular pipe-like functions of [`pipe()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) and [`close()`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?close%202). The pipe is meant to use as a channel of communication between a father process and his child process, meaning the program will use [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), probably more than once.

My idea is to implement it using an malloc in the `pipe()` function that will be freed in the `close()` function, but when the fork command happens I will end up with more than one process holding  a file descriptor to my pipe, and this is the part that I can't figure out:

How can i know how many times `fork()` has been called and how many process has access to my pipe?
How do i prevent a process that closes its access to one end of the pipes from closing it for all others? How can I make sure that the last process that closes the pipe will free its memory?

> **Update**

Actually it is meant to work with file descriptors, and the processes don't manage this memory, they only have access to it, I need a way to prevent from the closing of one end by a process from closing it before it is closed by all others, and to make sure that once all ends are closed the memory is freed.

Comment: With fork you get completely separated processes, each with its own memory. So a naïve approach with just a malloc won't work - you should free the memory in _every_ forked process

Comment: Are you doing this inside the kernel, or are you simulating it in ordinary user space code?  I assume the latter, but it complicates your life, not least because one of the child processes could itself fork, and tracking that back will be hard.  There are advantages to being in the kernel where such tracking can be done properly.

Comment: if you actually wish to implement pipes without using kernel pipes, I would take a look at e.g. [shared memory segments](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html), see a tutoral [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/shm.html). But obviously it's not a complete do-it-yourself implementation

Comment: The memory is being malloced by a diffrent prosse, and both father and son just get a referance to that memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not sure what is the diffrence, I am doing it simply using c code, note that it should run on a server to which I do not have root accese.

Comment: Well, while it's been malloc-ed once, after a fork you get two completely separated processes, a _copy_ of each other (literally, a copy, the only initial difference between them is `fork()` return value. But once one of the processes changes anything in its memory, another won't see the changes anymore (unless, the changed memory is explicitly `shared memory`, i.e. one which allocated with `shmget()` & co)

Comment: OK; that's regular user space code (as I suspected), not inside the kernel.  Tracking how many processes have your pipe open is going to be hard.

Comment: @user3159253, the memory belongs and beeing managed by a diffrent proscces, the only thing that is duplicated is the accses to that memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ya, that is what i thoght two..

Comment: With (a standard) `malloc()` you won't memory shared between processes. So the question how to count references from forked processes simply doesn't make sense as each process gets a _single_ reference to its _own_ memory structure. Or maybe I miss something in your explanations?

Comment: A pipe has two ends. You can count them with a single finger: 0, 1. One process writes things at one end, another process reads things at the other end. It rarely, if ever, makes sense to share the same pipe end between several processes.

Comment: @n.m. even dou it rearly makes sence my implemntation still neads to support it. Any way even so, I stil need to prevent the closing of one end, for example the write by the son, from closing it for the father.

Comment: In order to support this, you need synchronization. Accessing shared memory without synchronization is undefined. Once you have synchronization you can add a reference counter to the same shared memory and protect it by the same synchronization mechanism. Note that synchronization is voluntary, you cannot force processes to have it, so you can just as well rely on voluntary reference counting.

Comment: @petric, I think it would be useful if you would give the full description of your *original* problem. The user space pipe, as you have imagined it, is literally impossible in user-space (e.g. custom file descriptors require writing a kernel-space module).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is to implement something like `pipe()`, but without actually using `pipe()` (or even FDs), but instead using memory.

When a program executes a `fork()`, its FDs are available to both child and parent. So, with a `pipe()`, the child can write and the parent can read (or vice versa). However, the child inherits a copy-on-write copy of the parent's memory. So any write performed by the child will not be seen by the parent and vice versa. If you use threads, on the other hand, the memory map is truly shared.

What you are trying to do is a form of IPC (Interprocess Communication). If you don't want to use memory, you will need a special type of memory. One way to do this is to use `shmget`, `shmctl` etc. - there are examples [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html).

However, you will have to manage memory allocations yourself, rather than use `malloc()` and `free()`. `malloc()` and `free()` operate on the heap, which will not use shared memory segments.

For completeness the answer to your question is technically that parent and all children must *each* free any allocation the parent made before the `fork()`, as they each not only have a copy of the allocated memory, but also of the memory allocation control structures. However, they effectively each have a different allocation containing the same data (implemented via copy-on-write).

Comment: Actually it is meant to work with file descriptors, and the processes don't manage this memory, they only have access to it, I need a way to prevent from the closing of one end by a process from closing it before it is closed by all others, and to make sure that once all ends are closed the memory is freed.

Comment: @petric: If you care which end closes the pipe first, then simply don't close the other end until the end that needs to close first has done so. You can use the normal FD semantics to work out that the pipe has closed (e.g. `select` says it's ready to read but `read` gives 0 bytes). Then make the last end to close do the freeing.

Comment: My implentation will be tested not only by my code, so I cant realy control which end close and when.

Comment: I think you might need to clarify your question. If the other end reliably closes the connection, then simply close your end after that. If the other end does not reliably close the connection, and you can't free the shared memory until its closed, as far as I can see you could wait indefinitely for it to close it.

Comment: The other end will close its connection, the problem is that i don't know how many processes will have my FD, and I can't know who is the last to close it and free the memory.

Comment: @petric - are you saying there are multiple processes on the other end of *separate* pipes? If so, just maintainer a counter. Or are there multiple processes on the other end of the same pipe, e.g. because the other end has `fork()`'d or `dup()`'d the FD? If so, I believe the closure detection will successfully detect when the last of those has closed the other end of the pipe (if you think about it, that must be so or closing all FDs after `fork()` would be dangerous).

Comment: It is the latter option, what is this "closure detection"?
if it is not clear I am the one writing the "pipe library", any thing I would not do by myself will not get done automatically

Comment: By 'closure detection' I mean either reading from a pipe that `select()` says is ready to read and getting 0 bytes (the standard read side close detection), or writing to a pipe that `select()` says is ready to write and getting `EPIPE` (the standard write-side closure detection).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you have in  mind, but some options are:

1. Use a named semaphore each child opens and increments, wait for it to return to 0 in the parent.  This is the easiest and most efficient.
2. Get the PID of each child and use one of the wait functions 'wait(), wait3(), wait4(), waitpid()' to make sure they have all exited.  The program might hang if your children don't exit.
3. Parse the output of the system 'lsof' command.  This command can be run directly on named files, not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should check the waitpid manual, used with execve().
it gives you the return value of your son process.

you can check my own implementation on github :

https://github.com/sirignano/environnement_unix_1/tree/master/42sh

i think
ft_pipe.c and ft_use.c
is what you are looking for.
(not really sure :D)